# Custom validation & role providers in ASP.NET MVC5 with ASP.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've previously used ExtendedMembershipProvider and RoleProvider with MVC and not had a problem, but now that I'm trying to use MVC5 with Identity, i'm finding it pretty tough to adapt what I had to the new way of doing this.

I can find plenty of examples of how to add properties to a user class with code-first, but that's not what I want to do.. I have an existing database with usernames and passwords, and I would like to be able to do the equivalent of overriding the previous auth provider and having my own logic in there. The same goes for the Roles, but again I have found very little in the way of doing this with the new Identity method.

Has anyone managed to implement this with MVC 5? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I too have searched for this but not been able to find anything useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19845909/179261 is this what you want?

Comment: It looks like a step in the right direction, thanks. I would go back to the older style of FormsAuthentication in MVC4/VS2012 before putting login validation logic in my controllers though, that seems like a step backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the comment from Bcelik & these links,

http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/

[Setting up Forms Authentication for multiple Web Apps in MVC 5 based on OWIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770001/setting-up-forms-authentication-for-multiple-web-apps-in-mvc-5-based-on-owin/19845909#19845909)

I've been able to make a separate class for authentication & call it in place of the UserManager.
As far as the roles go, I ended up getting my role information from the database in question (my own DB helper class) and inserting them into the Role section of the claim that's built when the user is authenticated, and this works well with the Authorize attributes like I'm used to.