# User registration and authentication

Tags: authentication, authorization, registration, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I develop a web application. It has a three-tier architecture (data access layer, a business logic layer and the presentation layer). A data access layer is implemented with a NHibernate ORM (S#arp Architecture). I have the following table:

```
public partial class Role {
    public Role()
    {
        this.Users = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<User>();
    }

    public virtual long Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<User> Users
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public partial class User {

    public User()
    {
        this.Drivers = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<Driver>();
        this.UserPhotos = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<UserPhoto>();
        this.Roles = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<Role>();
    }

    public virtual long Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Login
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Email
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Salt
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Hash
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Driver> Drivers
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual University University
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<UserPhoto> UserPhotos
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Role> Roles
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public partial class Driver {
    public Driver()
    {
        this.Trips = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<Trip>();
    }

    public virtual long Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Car Car
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public virtual User User
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Trip> Trips
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

There is a **User** in the system. Table **Driver** inherits the user table. Each user in the system may have several roles.

I want to implement a few things.

1) User registration. Is it a correct way to implement this features?

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserTasks userTasks;

    public AccountController(IUserTasks userTasks)
    {
        this.userTasks = userTasks;
    }

    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var userToCreate = this.userTasks.Create(model);

            return View(customerToCreate);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

2) User authentication. Is it a correct way to implement this features?

```
// GET: /Account/Login
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}

// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user =  userTasks.Find(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            ///......
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

3) User authorization. User authorization. I want to write some attribute, for example,

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

I do not know how to do it.

In many examples a new library **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity** is used. Should I use it? There is a implementation **NHibernate.AspNet.Identity**. However, I do not understand what benefit I get from this.

Also I do not know how to implement user authentication.

I'll be glad if you tell me a vector for further research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices. Either:

- you use OWIN as explained in [Setting up Forms Authentication for multiple Web Apps in MVC 5 based on OWIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770001/setting-up-forms-authentication-for-multiple-web-apps-in-mvc-5-based-on-owin)
- you use traditional form-based authentication. See here: [MVC 5 External authentication with authentication mode=Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893718/mvc-5-external-authentication-with-authentication-mode-forms/19931118#19931118)

As for authorization, Microsoft provides something called claims-based authorization which lets you define user and resource claims and define authorization constraints based on them. Have a look here: [Using Claim-Based Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457506/using-claim-based-authorization)

Alternatively, you could look into [XACML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML), the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language. That will require additional libraries outside the .NET framework though. XACML gives you policy-based, fine-grained authorization.

HTH